# How to define scrapy LinkExtractor rule to follow all links ending with .css?

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I am trying to follow all css stylesheets of a website, e.g. https://www.thomann.de/de/index.html

I'm inheriting from the scrapy CrawlSpider class and using the LxmlLinkExtractor. I am telling the Rule to search for the str "css" in all "link" tags as follows:

```py
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from items import ShopCrawlerItem

class CSSSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # define unique name of spider
    name = "cssspider"

    # define spider specific settings
    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 0,
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'data/interim/items_css.json',
    }

    def __init__(self, start_urls, *args, **kwargs):

        # load list of start urls 
        self.start_urls = ["https://www.thomann.de/de/index.html"]


        # define rules to find css stylesheets
        self.rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(tags="link", allow="css"), callback="parse_item", follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        """
        Function to parse crawl responses.
        """
        # initialize items
        item = ShopCrawlerItem()

        # store data as items
        item["shopurl"] = response.request.url
        item["html"] = response.body.decode("utf-8")

        return item
```

However, I am only receiving 2 items in my json file:

```
[
{"shopurl": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,400i&subset=latin-ext,latin", "html": "xyz"}, 
{"shopurl": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora", "html": "xyz"}
]
```

The found items look like this in the html source code:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,400i&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Altough I found a bunch of links ending with ".css" in the Chrome Debugger, such as:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/nc/css/oo__rev43.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/tr/css/nc-fix__rev928.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Does anybody has a clue what am I missing here to find all css stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `tags` and `attrs` constructor parameters of your link extractor accordingly.

Their default values will not work for your use case:

```py
tags=('a', 'area'), attrs=('href',)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the `tags` and `attrs` paramter to 
`tags=("link"), attrs=('href',)`
Still my rule doesn't seem to catch all link tags...

Comment: That’s a common Python mistake, `("link")` is equivalent to `("l", "i", "n", "k")`. Use `("link",)` instead.

Comment: Mmh I now wrote `tags=("link",), attrs=("href",)` as you told me. However, there seems to be some difference between the google css and the other css files in this html... I am still getting only google fonts.